# Wordpress: list all the URLs / routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, wordpress

I want to see a list of all the (rewritten) URLs that my WP site is using. Basically, if you're familiar with Rails, I want `rake routes`... but for Wordpress.

If it matters, the reason is this. I'm writing code to exist next to an existing Wordpress site and I keep bumping against a problem where my new code is accessible at the same URL that Wordpress or one of it's plugins is using. I keep having to monkey with the .htaccess file. It would be much easier to just see a list of every URL that's taken and just avoid them.

Answer (score 15):

i'm new to wp, but i think you are after [$wp_rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

at the right hook do a:

```
global $wp_rewrite;  
print_r($wp_rewrite->rules);
```

if nothing is printed, remove `->rules` and print whole object

hopefully a starting point :)

Comment: it's not picking up my add_rewrite_rule()

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked over at [Wordpress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules), where several helpful suggestions are made, notably the use of a few plugins for this purpose:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/askapaches-rewriterules-viewer/

Neither have been updated in over 2 years, but I've just successfully installed them locally on WordPress 3.7.

Ask Apache's plugin installs and activates fine, but looks like some of the debugging info is outdated, and otherwise provides more detail than is useful for me.

The Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer provides a formatted & more interactive representation of `[@gwillie's snippet][2]`. Works for me!